# Checking for a blank line in C - Regex

Tags: c, regex, string-parsing

**Goal:**

- Find if a string contains a blank line. Whether it be `'\n\n',
  '\r\n\r\n', '\r\n\n', '\n\r\n'`

**Issues:**

- I don't think my current regex for finding `'\n\n'` is right. This is my first time really using regex outside of simple use of * when removing files in command line.
- Is it possible to check for all of these cases (listed above) in one regex? or do I have to do 4 seperate calls to compile_regex?

**Code:**

```
int checkForBlankLine(char *reader) {
    regex_t r;
    compile_regex(&r, "*\n\n");
    match_regex(&r, reader);

    return 0;
}

void compile_regex(regex_t *r, char *matchText) {
    int status;
    regcomp(r, matchText, 0); 
}

int match_regex(regex_t *r, char *reader) {
    regmatch_t match[1];
    int nomatch = regexec(r, reader, 1, match, 0);
    if (nomatch) {
        printf("No matches.\n");
    } else {
        printf("MATCH!\n");
    } 
    return 0;
}
```

**Notes:**

- I only need to worry about finding one blank line, that's why my `regmatch_t match[1]` is only one item long
- reader is the char array containing the text I am checking for a blank line.
- I have seen other examples and tried to base the code off of those examples, but I still seem to be missing something.

Thank you kindly for the help/advice.

If anything needs to be clarified please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check what the `*` in a regex means. It's not like the wildcard "anything" in the command line. The `*` means that the previous component can appear any amount of times. The wildcard in regex is the `.`. So if you want to say `match anything` you can do `.*`, which would be anything, any amount of times.

So in your case you can do `.*\n\n.*` which would match anything that has `\n\n`.

Finally, you can use `or` in a regex and `( )` to group stuff. So you can do something like `.*(\n\n|\r\n\r\n).*` And that would match anything that has a `\n\n` or a `\r\n\r\n`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my misunderstanding of the wildcard - that helped alot.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you have to compile the regex as extended:

```
regcomp(&re, "\r?\n\r?\n", REG_EXTENDED);
```

The first atom, `\r?` is probably unnecessary, because it doesn't add to the blank-line condition if you don't capture the result.

In the above, blank line really means empty line. If you want blank line to mean a line that has no characters except for white space, you can use:

```
regcomp(&re, "\r?\n[ \t]*\r?\n", REG_EXTENDED);
```

(I don't think you can use the space character pattern, `\s` here instead of `[ \t]`, because that would include carriage return and new-line.)

As others have already hinted at, the "simple use of `*` in the command line` is not a regular expression. This wildcard-matching is called file globbing and has different semantics.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than looking for only `\r` or `\n`, look for *not* `\r` or `\n`?

Your regex would simply be

```
'[^\r\n]'
```

and a match result of false indicates a blank line to your specification.

Comment: I guess there is something I am confused about, what does regexec() return when there is nomatch? Also would `[^\r\n]` return false for single newline chars? I'm looking for two \n\n I tried `*[^\r\n]+[^\n]` but I don't think that worked

Comment: @user1787262 Is your question about exact matches to *only* the examples you showed, or is it about matching a string containing only carriage-returns and/or newlines? You are just as capable as I am to search for the return value from regexec().

Comment: sorry Andrew I had looked at the man page for it but somehow missed it. I found it now. I am looking for a string that contains any of the examples I listed at the top of the question.